# laravel 5.1 embedding video

Tags: php, laravel

I am new into laravel and php and I am trying to set up in Laravel 5.1 a section in a form where a user can type in url from youtube, and then after submitting it the video can be embedded in his page and then edited if needed later. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!
This is how I tried to set up in controller:

```
public function postCreateVideo(CreateVideoRequest $request)
        {
          $user = Auth::user();
        }
        Video::create
        (
            [
                'video' => $request->get('video_id'),
                'user_id' => $user->id
            ]
        );

        return redirect('validated/videos/')->with(['video_created' =>'The video has been created']);
         }
public function VideoID($video_url)
    {
        if(strlen($video_url) > 11)
        {
            if (preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $video_url, $match))
            {
                return $match[1];
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        return $video_id;
    }
public function setKeyAttribute($value)
  {
    $this->attributes['key'] = $this->VideoId($value);
  }

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting now? In other words can you explain why the above code snippet doesn't do what you want it to?

Comment: I get that my other variable are undefined, which is not the case when I leave out video embed option: {"id":51,"title":"","description":"dfsdf","user_id":6,"created_at":"2015-07-08 12:43:42","updated_at":"2015-07-08 12:43:42","path":"\/img\/c0b48cabc9f760b6c314587cd33194ca5f20a530.jpeg","video_id":""} (View: /home/vagrant/Projects/ScenenAdmin/resources/views/shows/show.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

In your method, I see this:

```
return $video_id;
```

But $video_id is never set. I think that's why this code doesn't work.

Further, you return different type of values:

- $match[1], which is an alphanumeric value(?)
- false, which is a boolean
- $video_id (now not set), but you mean an integer

It's better to return always the same type in a method.